# knockout.js with nested foreach loop

Tags: json, foreach, knockout.js

I am working with knockout.js 2.0 and when i do a nested foreach loop the performance is extremely slow.  The main loop has about 70 records being returned and the array inside those 70 json records contain anywhere from 0 - 20 items.  So i feel this is not alot of json data.

I am just testing with the below code:

```
    <table>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: Employees, visible: Employees().length > 0">  
            <tr>                
                <td class="centerdata" data-bind="text: ID"></td>
                <td class="centerdata" data-bind="text: Name"></td>
                <td>
                   <table>
                       <tbody data-bind="foreach: $data.Transactions">  
                           <tr>   
                              <td data-bind="text:TransDate"></td>
                           </tr>
                       </tbody>
                   </table>
                </td>
            </tr>                    
        </tbody>
   </table>
```

The page takes about 20 seconds to load.  There are other fields inside the json, but I have removed them for simplicity.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/pull/272 and try testing your app with the latest KO version from github: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/tree/master/build/output.  You should see some decent improvements that will be included in KO 2.1.

Comment: We tried using the latest knockout and also name templated both foreach loops, but the performance is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there must be something else going on here, Matthew.

I have knocked up a quick fiddle, using your markup with some dummy data of a similar size to what you mention and the performance is ~1 second in Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/unklefolk/DCLaR/

Is there a dependent observable that is being repeatedly calculated? If so, take a look at the throttle functionality (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/throttle-extender.html)